# Can't get SDL2 to work with MinGW, VSCode and CMake on Windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sdl-2, vcpkg

I want to use VS Code, mingw and Cmake on Windows 10. I made a simple app:

```
-SDL2
-main.cpp
-CMakeLists.txt
```

This is the current content of my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.0)

project(main VERSION 1.0.0)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH SDL2)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

I also have a `SDL2Config.cmake` inside my SDL2 folder:

```
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include")

# Support both 32 and 64 bit builds
if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
  set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib")
else ()
  set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib")
endif ()

string(STRIP "${SDL2_LIBRARIES}" SDL2_LIBRARIES)
```

Building this results in 'SDL.h' not found, this is the include `#include<SDL2.h>`.

I also tried "vcpkg", this comes with `triplets`, the `x64-windows` triplet allows me to find the file but it wont compile since it's meant for VSCommunity. I tried the other triplets for mingw `x64-mingw-dynamic` and `x64-mingw-static` but they both failed building the package. This is the command I used to install SDL2 `vcpkg install SDL2:triplet` where `triplet` is one of the above mentioned.

Comment: ***but they both failed building the package*** You probably need to file a bug report at the vcpkg site.

Comment: Is this the problem: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/11900](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/11900)

Comment: I suppose I can't use vcpkg then, but what could I be doing wrong using cmake to include SDL2? Seems like I'm missing something in the process.

Comment: `target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})` should be `target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, sadly it doesn't change anthing. I still can't build, it's telling me "SDL2.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Maybe `SDL2.h` is not in the folder `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include`

Comment: It works? I have no idea what happend. I used vspkg to install the x64-windows triplet, compiled with msvc, added `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` above the include and it now compiles even with mingw. VSCode intellisense still complains about the include tho.I don't think this is the solution

Comment: In Visual Studio code Intelisense has a separate include path from compiling both are configured in different .json files.

Comment: I suppose you mean this `"${workspaceFolder}/**"` How can I tell vscode to look for SDL2? It's at the root level, so basicly inside the workspceFolder

Comment: I was talking about `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: Me too, I put `"${workspaceFolder}/SDL2/include/**"` inside the includePath there but intellisense still can't find it.

Comment: I see, I have no idea then. I mainly use Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `vcpkg` you need to set the toolchain file somewhere.
Either in `CMakeLists.txt` or you can set it in a command line argument:

#### 1. `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
  CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")
```

NB! Make sure that you get the path right!

#### 2. As command line argument (I personally prefer this for easier portability)

```sh
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:<your-path>/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

Read this on [vcpkg integration](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md).
The [manifest mode](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications/manifests/) is the ultimate pro tip, as this leads to clean `CMakeLists.txt`file and a fully portable (and painless) process.

Comment: Thanks for the manifest tip, I have seen it in a video and it looks promising. I have had it working with vcpkg but only with msvc, not with mingw. It seems that mingw has some problems https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/11900

Comment: You are welcome. Try to set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, it needs to be set anyways though. You may take a look at one of my projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/psnx/CppND-Capstone-SDL2-Game-Demo).

Comment: I did as you told me and now I see why you recommend it. Just add one entry to the json, two entries to CMakeLists.txt and build. Very nice, thanks for the tip